# Scalc SBT compile failing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I am trying to follow code from below link
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html

But when I am trying to create package it is failing. I want to know 2 thinks

1. obviously, why it is failing
2. why it is showing older version of the scala, while I mentioned 2.11

Below is the error message.

```
[info] Set current project to default-0464ce (in build file:/home/ubuntu/simple_sbt/)
[info] Updating {file:/home/ubuntu/simple_sbt/}default-0464ce...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.9.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/ubuntu/simple_sbt/target/scala-2.9.1/classes...
[error] /home/ubuntu/simple_sbt/src/main/scala/SimpleApp.scala:1: object apache is not a member of package org
[error] import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
[error]            ^
[error] /home/ubuntu/simple_sbt/src/main/scala/SimpleApp.scala:2: object apache is not a member of package org
[error] import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
[error]            ^
[error] two errors found
[error] {file:/home/ubuntu/simple_sbt/}default-0464ce/compile:compile: Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Aug 30, 2016 3:19:18 AM
```

Comment: `while I mentioned 2.11` this is kind of vague, how did you "mention" exactly?

Comment: I suspect you're using an old sbt version. Check it with `sbt sbt-version` and verify it's 0.13.x

Comment: Hi, As per the link I mentioned it in the simple.sbt file.

Answer (score 0):

when you run **sbt package** , sometimes it fails as there are no dependencies that are downloaded and will be resolved for the files imported. 
Try running, **sbt run** first and then **sbt package** . sbt run should bring in all the dependencies on top of which packaging and compiling will be possible.

If the above does not solves your problem, you need to share your sbt build file and the environment that you are using. In which directory you are running these commands, will also play a role.

Comment: Thanks, I will check and let you know.